# "Trying to get property of non-object" when executing test of a JSON request on Symfony 4.1

Tags: json, object, testing, phpunit, symfony4

I'm trying to write a test case to test my operation to persist data into the database using Symfony 4.1. The operation is already working and it is the following:

```
public function storeAction(Request $request)
{
    $data = json_decode($request->getContent());

    try {
        $entityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

        $createdAt = \DateTime::createFromFormat("Y-m-d H:i:s", $data->createdAt);
        $concludedAt = \DateTime::createFromFormat("Y-m-d H:i:s", $data->concludedAt);

        $task = new Task();
        $task->setDescription($data->description);
        $task->setCreatedAt($createdAt);
        $task->setConcludedAt($concludedAt);

        $entityManager->persist($task);
        $entityManager->flush();


        return $this->json([
            "message" => "Task created",
            "status" => 200
        ]);
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        return $this->json([
            "error" => [
                "code" => 500,
                "message" => $e->getMessage(),
                "file" => $e->getFile()
            ]
        ]);
    }
}
```

Using Insonmnia REST with it sending a JSON works. But the test will show me

> Trying to get property 'createdAt' of non-object

pointing to my controller class. This is the test:

```
public function testStoreTaskEndpointStatusCode200AndTaskCreated()
{
    $client = static::createClient();
    $client->request(
        "POST",
        "/tasks",
        [],
        [],
        [
            "CONTENT_TYPE" => "application/json",
            '{"description": "Goodbye, world!", "createdAt": "2012-12-21 00:00:00", "concludedAt": "2012-12-21 00:00:01"}'
        ]
    );

    $obj = json_decode($client->getResponse()->getContent());

    var_dump($obj); // <~ the error message is shown

    $this->assertEquals(200, $client->getResponse()->getStatusCode());
    $this->assertTrue($client->getResponse()->headers->contains("Content-Type", "application/json"));
}
```

The documentation shows this way to send JSON to the controller for testing purposes. So, why does it fail?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should pass the content data as seven argument of the request method as example:

```
$client->request(
        "POST",
        "/tasks",
        [],
        [],
        [
            "CONTENT_TYPE" => "application/json",
        ],
            '{"description": "Goodbye, world!", "createdAt": "2012-12-21 00:00:00", "concludedAt": "2012-12-21 00:00:01"}'

    );
```

PS: I suggest you to check if the json_encode find errors by checking

```
$obj = json_decode($client->getResponse()->getContent());

if (false === $obj) {
   // Invalid json provided
}
```

Comment: Oh. Odd, because their example shows as I did. It worked, thank you.